# User defined worksheet function returns #VALUE! error instead of cell color index

Tags: vba, excel, cell

Can someone please help me understand the problem with this function:

```
'the function returns the DISPLAYED color of specified cell
Public Function cellDisplayCol(ByRef c As Range) As Long
   cellDisplayCol = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Sub test()
   MsgBox cellDisplayCol(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```

the test works as expected but when I use the function in worksheet cell:
=cellDisplayCol(A1)

it returns #VALUE! error...

Any ideas why? What should I fix?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking on msdn, it appears you cannot use `.DisplayFormat` in UDF's:

> Note that the `DisplayFormat` property does not work in user defined functions. For example, in a worksheet function that returns the interior color of a cell, you use a line similar to:
>   `Range(n).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`. When the worksheet function executes, it returns a `#VALUE!` error.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Gareth for your research. My problem is that I need the DISPLAYED color of a cell because the (suggested) ColorIndex property is not affected by conditional formatting. The actual displayed color is critical for me and I can't find another way to get it without translating/copying the actual (very complex) conditional formatting logic to the function. Any suggestions? Directions? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxSegal To avoid code duplication, put the color selection logic in a VBA function, and call it both from your cell and from the conditional formatting rules.