# Function to count condition color gives #error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel 2010 Function that keeps returning the #value error.

The function counts the number of cells from a range that are a particular color defined based on the cell specified.

I can't really use CountIFs as the conditional formula's are to complex.

If I define the same ranges selected with the function as a Sub in VBA is works fine.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
Function CountCellsByConditionColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long    

    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Dim cntCells As Long
    Dim indCurCell As Long

    Application.Volatile

    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    cntCells = rData.CountLarge

    For indCurCell = 1 To cntCells
        If indRefColor = rData(indCurCell).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next

    CountCellsByConditionColor = cntRes        

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you cannot use DisplayFormat in functions directly on worksheets, see in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648240/user-defined-worksheet-function-returns-value-error-instead-of-cell-color-inde) or directly on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx).

You can, however, try to combine this function with Worksheet_Change trigger. It will not be as pratcical as having your own UDF, but the results could be satisfactory, depending on how dynamic or complex your finished result should look like.

Comment: That won't work, will bring back 0. The Interior.Color = none as the color is being displayed by the conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks, that is a rather annoying bug :( I will post back here with any updates, determined to solve it.

Comment: It is annoying, I stumbled across the same restriction once as well. I edited the post once more, try to use the Worksheet_Change trigger to work in your favor, it may help you.

Comment: With the amount I need to reuse it I think ill just have to have a public sub that I call when I need it to calculate as opposed to the worksheet_change trigger. I will leave this open a few days then mark your answer as correct. Thank you :)