# Count where Color set with Conditional Format

Tags: vba, excel

I used a conditional format =B2=MAX(Relative Range) to highlight across all rows the max value contained within them.

I'm trying to count how many instances of color X has appeared in this column.

i.e. Column A2:1000 - this would have 5 high-lighted instances.

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
        End If
    Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

This is the code I have taken from http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1155-excel-count-sum-cells-by-color.html. The counting fails because of my conditional format. It reads the cells as being "white" because it doesn't interpret the conditional format.

Here's a snapshot of how some of the data is arranged for reference. [image: Sample Snapshot of Data]

Comment: Colors applied using conditional formatting cannot be read directly using `ColorIndex` or `Color`.  If you're using XL2010+ you can try `DisplayFormat` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff838814(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried replacing ColorIndex with DisplayFormat but it doesn't work unfortunately as it results in a VALUE# Error. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Try `lCol = rColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: Hi Tim, I gave that a shot but it still results in error. I thought it was because I was referencing an empty cell that was colored green, but I tried referencing a cell which was colored via conditional format and received the same result.

Comment: Works for me.  With a cell containing conditional formatting (and colored Red by that CF) selected, `selection.interior.color` gives me 16777215 and `selection.displayformat.interior.color` gives me 255

Comment: Sorry - I missed that you seem to be using your function as a UDF.  My `displayformat` suggestion won't work in that use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648240/user-defined-worksheet-function-returns-value-error-instead-of-cell-color-inde

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to VBA so I'll try follow. The 'n' it refers to - is this an instantiated variable? "Range(n).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex"? I apologize for the multiple comments.

Comment: The post I linked to explains that you can't use DisplayFormat from within a function which is called from a worksheet cell (ie. a User-Defined Function or "UDF").  That `Range(n)` part is just a generic example of addressing a Range.

Comment: Not a problem. So the solution is that it can't be done due to those limitations right? Well, I'll certainly keep trying and hopefully I can work out a solution I can post back to everyone. Thanks for trying!

Comment: How about something like `=COUNTIF(A2:A1000,MAX(A2:A1000))`.  Not sure i really follow your setup though.

Comment: Hi Tim, I've included an image showing how the data is arranged. There are multiple columns with multiple dates. So each row is compared and the maximum date for that row is high-lighted via the CF. Now that the CF is all complete, we have to sort out how many CFs each criteria has (so we can identify which column has the highest max date values). Does this help with expanding on my setup?

Comment: The image was very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine Sum based conditional formatting rule with formula `=B2=MAX(Relative Range)`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ColorFunction(rRange As Range, Optional getSum As Boolean = False)
    Dim cel As Range, r As Long, c As String, ur As Range, lr As Long, v As Long

    For Each cel In rRange
        With cel
            If Len(cel) > 0 And IsNumeric(cel) Then 'IsDate(cel)
                If .FormatConditions.Count = 1 Then
                    If InStr(1, .FormatConditions.Item(1).Formula1, "#") = 0 Then
                        v = .Value2
                        c = Split(.Address(True, False), "$")(0)
                        lr = .Parent.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                        Set ur = .Parent.Range(c & "2:" & c & lr)

                        If WorksheetFunction.Max(ur) = v Then r = r + IIf(getSum, v, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ColorFunction = r
End Function
```

This code is very specific to your case:

- it only works with one conditional formatting rule
- that rule is MAX(range) and is hard-coded in main logic
- it's not based on color (may be an advantage in some cases)
- to work with date values instead of numbers replace `IsNumeric(cel)` with `IsDate(cel)`

I used the following conditional formatting rules (in 4 columns):

- `=A2=MAX(A$2:A$7)`
- `=B2=MAX(B$2:B$7)`
- `=C2=MAX(C$2:C$7)`
- `=D2=MAX(D$2:D$7)`

CF manager:
[image: CF manager]

Result:
[image]

Note: @Tim's comments helped identify other key requirements such as UDF

.

To determine total rows (initial answer):

```
Option Explicit

Sub countRowsWithConditionalColor()
    Dim totalRows As Long, rng As Range, lColor As Long, cel As Range, lRow As Long

    lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    lColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'change color accordingly

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=lColor, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        For Each cel In rng
            If cel.RowHeight > 0 Then totalRows = totalRows + 1
            If cel.Row > lRow Then Exit For
        Next
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "TotalRows: " & totalRows
End Sub
```

---

- turns off ScreenUpdating, so this process is not visible to the user (and faster)
- applies an AoutoFileter on column 1, color to filter by, and "Operator:=xlFilterCellColor"

  - loops through all cells in the column
  - if current cell has a height > 0 (is visible) increments the counter (totalRows)
- turns ScreenUpdating back on
- shows the total rows

Notes:

- My test color (vbRed) is generated by a conditional formatting rule
- Tim's suggestion `rColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` might be better suited for your code if it works

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried your code but I don't think it suits the purpose I require at the moment. I tried the color code to RGB (146,208,80) but it doesn't work. It outputs a rows value which I don't need at this point in time unfortunately. Could you explain how your code works..?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Paul. I'll give it a crack and let you know if I have any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer is pretty good and easy to understand. Just make sure you select right column by changing value after "Field:=". 1 stands for col. A, 2 for B etc. Also make sure you have autofilter turned on before running the macro. And also replace `.AutoFilter` bit with `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` after `End With`. This way it won't disable your autofilter.

Comment: Thanks Kotty, but my initial answer didn't provide the solution to OP's specific question: it determines total rows instead of total columns. I left it part of the updated answer as a reference