# Getting cell Interior Color Fails when range passed from Worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get write a simple function one can call from a cell that would return if the background of a given cell has a specific background color.

This function works as expected when called from a sub-routine, but fails when called from the worksheet.  At the line

```
IntColor = Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

Here is all of the code

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetCellRGB(Rng As Range) As Integer()
    Dim Result(1 To 3) As Integer
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Cell = Rng.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim IntColor As Integer

    ' when called from worksheet, function exits here with a #VALUE error
    IntColor = Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

    Result(1) = IntColor Mod 256 ' red
    Result(2) = IntColor \ 256 Mod 256 ' green
    Result(3) = IntColor \ 65536 Mod 256 ' blue

    GetCellRGB = Result
End Function

Public Function IsColor(Rng As Range, R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Vals() As Integer

    Vals = GetCellRGB(Rng)
    If R = Vals(1) And G = Vals(2) And B = Vals(3) Then
        IsColor = True
    Else
        IsColor = False
    End If
End Function

' This works as expected
Sub ColorTest()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Debug.Print IsColor(Rng, 255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `DisplayFormat` doesn't work in a UDF  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648240/user-defined-worksheet-function-returns-value-error-instead-of-cell-color-inde  PS will not help in this case but you should be using Long not Integer

Comment: thank you, yes that seems to be the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a workaround to the "DisplayFormat not available in a UDF" problem.

It uses `Evaluate` to side-step the UDF context

```
Public Function DFColor(addr)
    DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

Function CFColorMatches(rng As Range, R As Long, G As Long, B As Long)
    CFColorMatches = (rng.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(""" & rng.Address & """)") = RGB(R, G, B))
End Function
```

Note also you really don't need all that RGB-related code

Comment: Using Evaluate to side-step the UDF context is brilliant, but why is it qualified with rng.Parent.Evaluate?

Comment: There is both an `Application.Evaluate` (uses the ActiveSheet as the default context for evaluating a formula) and a `Worksheet.Evaluate` form (uses the provided worksheet object as the context).  Typically you want the latter version, otherwise you run the risk of evaluating the formula against the wrong worksheet.  `rng.Parent` provides the worksheet context.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Perhaps it would be better to use `rng.Address(External:=True)`. Also, I found it necessary to make the UDF `Application.Volatile`; otherwise, it would not update when the workbook is opened.

Answer (score 2):

RGB is calculated by VBA itself and you don't need to assume it is an array, it is a long integer in fact so if you want to check the background color of a cell you can just simply do this which will work on the worksheet too:

```
Public Function IsColor(Rng As Range, R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer) As Boolean
    If Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B) Then
        IsColor = True
    Else
        IsColor = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, its quite elegant.  If you are curious, I accepted the other answer because it directly addressed why my code was failing.

Comment: @VinceW. fair enough!