# Sum across rows and count rows less than 0

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to identify inventory shortages for each store and the type of bread I am supplying.

Example table showing the demand for each type of bread by store.

[image]

Row 8 is what I am trying to accomplish with a formula.
Based on the quantity on hand, I can conditionally format to highlight cells red or green based on shortages.
I can't get a formula to count the number of red cells.

I am thinking I need to use sumproduct.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B9:$B11<C9:C11))
```

The above works for identifying shortages for Store A (Column C). However, when dragged to column D and E it doesn't remember what the other stores needed.

I can't get the rows to sum without adding ALL rows in the range. I need each row to be individually compared to the qty on hand. I assume an array needs to be used.

Comment: Can you also show the expected outcome?

Comment: The expected outcome is in Row 8. Cell E8 is a good example of the expected outcome. There is one row that doesn't have enough supply for the stores.

Comment: You have to use a slightly esoteric formula to find row (yes I do mean row) totals - will try and post something later.

Comment: You need to change up your example numbers so that all of this is more clear. Is The shortages per store a **count** of shortages or is it the actual number subtracted?

Comment: For example, does this show how your solution should look in practice assuming you had larger amounts being used? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xva5Q.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the formula I mentioned. It uses a standard method with mmult to get the row totals of the matrix, then compares them with the amounts available:

```
=SUM(--($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))
```

entered in C8 and pulled across. Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

**EDIT**

OP has commented that it shouldn't be listed as a shortage if a store doesn't need a particular item, even if the stock of that item has been exhausted.

So there should be an extra condition for it to be registered as a shortage only if the current column has a number >0 in a particular row as well as the row sum being greater than the amount available:

```
=SUM((C9:C11>0)*($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))
```

If you wanted to select only some of the rows as well it would look like

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A9:$A11,{"Wheat","Rye"},0))*(C9:C11>0)*($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Tom Sharpe - If I wanted to add criteria to your formula, such as wheat and rye only, would I modify the MMULT formula?

Comment: I don't think you would change the MMULT part of the formula, just multiply by the condition so it would look like =SUM((($A9:$A11="Wheat")+($A9:$A11="Rye"))*($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))

Comment: Or you could do this =SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A9:$A11,{"Wheat","Rye"},0))*($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))

Comment: Hi Tom, I have a followup question. As I experiment with your formula some more I realized it is counting quantities needed of 0 as a shortage if there is not enough on hand for the previous store. For example, if store A requires wheat bread and there isn't enough to meet Store A's need, the shortage is passed on to each store after Store A. Regardless if stores B, C, D, E, etc need this type of bread. Do you have a suggestion on how requirements 0 can be ignored?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Will see if I can work out a way to modify the formula.

Comment: Tom, I really appreciate you coming back to help me out. I am looking at your revised formula and trying to integrate the matching you added to your other formula. It looks like in your revised formula you simply added ">0". If I try to add that to the following formula it voids the matching function:

=SUM((ISNUMBER(MATCH($A9:$A11,{"Wheat","Rye"},0))>0)*($B9:$B11<MMULT($C9:C11,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C9:C11)^0))))

I am assuming the ">0" is in the wrong spot?

Comment: Each time you add another condition you have to add another complete set of brackets with a multiplication sign - see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: FIXED TO WORK FOR CONDITIONAL FORMATTING**:

Paste this into the module:

```
Public Function CellColour(addr)
    CellColour = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

Function FINDRED(rng As Range)

    FINDRED = 0

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If (cell.Parent.Evaluate("CellColour(""" & cell.Address & """)") = RGB(255, 0, 0)) Then
            FINDRED = FINDRED + 1
        End If
    Next cell

End Function
```

You can then use this like a normal excel formula:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work if the cell is colored by conditional formatting though...

Comment: Thank you for the help. As BigBen pointed out I am using conditional formatting to color the cells.

Comment: You could possibly use the workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265973/9245853)