# Getting #Value! Error on worksheet, but VBA test sub returns what it should

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to use several posts I found in regards to using DisplayFormat within a UDF that loops. I am trying to count conditionally formatted cells. I can return the correct count in a test sub, but get a #VALUE! error in my worksheet.

I have tried many things, but the one I thought was most relevant was from a response by Tim Williams:

[Getting cell Interior Color Fails when range passed from Worksheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265819/getting-cell-interior-color-fails-when-range-passed-from-worksheet-function)

However, the EVALUATE method would cause "Error 2015" values and I was unable to get around that problem, I saw this issue while using the test sub routine.

WORKING ANSWER thanks to @BigBen:

```
Public Function DFColor(addr)
DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Function COUNTBYCOLOUR(CountRange As Range)
Dim countColour As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
countColour = 3
For Each rCell In CountRange
   If countColour = (rCell.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(""" & rCell.Address & """)"))Then
    COUNTBYCOLOUR = COUNTBYCOLOUR + 1
    End If
Next rCell
End Function
```

Previous attempt Main Function:

```
Function COUNTBYCOLOUR(CountRange As Range)
'make workbook recalculate on cell changes
Application.Volatile
'Declaring variables
Dim countColour As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
'Setting search colour (red)
countColour = 3
'Looping through the defined range
For Each rCell In CountRange
Dim Y As Integer
Y = evalCell(rCell)
'Getting the count of matching colored cells
If Y = countColour Then
        COUNTBYCOLOUR = COUNTBYCOLOUR + 1
End If
Next rCell
End Function

'USE TO TEST UDF, Place cursor before Sub test() and press f8 to step through and debug
'Sub test()
 'MsgBox COUNTBYCOLOUR(Range("C4:C11"))
'End Sub
```

Previous attempt Secondary function to try and separate DisplayFormat from UDF:

```
'get cell colour outside of COUNTBYCOLOUR UDF so it evaluates DisplayFormat on worksheet.
Public Function evalCell(currentCell)
    evalCell = currentCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

When I run the sub routine at the bottom of my main function, I get the correct count (only trying to count red cells, no need to have a colour reference cell). When I use COUNTBYCOLOUR in my worksheet, I get the #VALUE! error. Hopefully some more experienced eyes can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you use `Evaluate` - as that is the key workaround as noted in the linked question?

Comment: I tried to implement the solution, it does not work for me. Hence I am asking for help

Comment: Can you share how you've used `Evaluate` then?

Comment: Yes Ben, Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I had overwritten, but it was along the lines I added in post above.

Comment: For starters, since you're using `ColorIndex` instead of `Color`, change `DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to `DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I had that done, I just quickly slapped this together from memory as I no longer had it. I will update in post now.

Comment: That version works for me. What is your data like and how are you calling the UDF?

Comment: Small note about *"USE TO TEST UDF, Place cursor before Sub test() and press f8 to step through and debug"*: a better way would be to hit Ctrl+G to bring up the *immediate pane*, and type `test` and ENTER.

Comment: I don't know what changed, but it works for me now as well, thank you so much @BigBen!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Working Version:

```
Public Function DFColor(addr)
DFColor = Range(addr).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Function COUNTBYCOLOUR(CountRange As Range)
Dim countColour As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
countColour = 3
For Each rCell In CountRange
If countColour = (rCell.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(""" & rCell.Address & """)"))Then
    COUNTBYCOLOUR = COUNTBYCOLOUR + 1
    End If
Next rCell
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is an overkill sorry. Following simplified form of your code works well for me:

```
Function COUNTBYCOLOUR(CountRange As Range)

Application.Volatile
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In CountRange 'Getting the count of matching colored cells
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then 'search colour (red) is 3
        COUNTBYCOLOUR = COUNTBYCOLOUR + 1
    End If
Next rCell

End Function
```

Comment: It will not work with colors set by conditional formatting.

Comment: `DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` is different than just `Interior.ColorIndex`.